# Updating the formula for large numbers of sum cell across multiple sheets

Tags: google-apps-script

I've got a spreadsheet with multiple formula like below (except for B4, C3 etc.)

=' NOV16'!B3+'DEC16'!B3+'JAN17'!B3+'FEB17'!B3+MARCH17!B3+'APR17'!B3+'MAY17'!B3+JUNE17!B3+JULY17!B3+AUGUST17!B3

I've created the script to create a new sheet and name it in the same format.  I can't workout the best way to add to the formula.

Is it possible to do something like:

```
var newSheetName = newSheet
var data = ss.getRange(2,2,10,10).getFormula()
```

Then add the newSheetName onto each formula and write it to the sheet?

Or is there a better alternative.

Sorry there isn't much code to work on with this.  I'm not sure where to even start with this part.

Comment: It would probably be helpful to show us your spreadsheet.

Comment: Hi Cooper,  Here's the  [spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1GeFzWx5mkJCPOpNU9PQe7K0Y9cmgkPvAPvWEChSsQDs/edit#gid=0)

So each month or so a new sheet will be added from the template and I want all of cells in the master sheet to incorporate this new sheet as well.

Comment: Tell me a little bit more about what your trying to do.

Comment: Sure thing.  The master sheet sums all the values for that cell in each sheet.  My current script creates a new sheet at the end based off the template.  What I want to do is each time a new sheet is created all of the formula that are across multiple sheets update to reflect the new sheet.

e.g. sheets 1-4
sheet 5 is created
master sheet formula are updated from =SUM(sheet1!B#+sheet2!B# etc.) to also have sheet 5 included.

Comment: So does the second script in the answer provide you with what you need to know or do you need more?

Comment: Hi Cooper,  I don't think it does.  It looks like that script sets the formula in the new sheet.  What I need to do is update the old/master sheet formula to include the new sheet in he original formula.  So when the new sheet is created the formula in the master sheet becomes =SUM(sumOldSheets!B3 + newSheet!B3) but also for all the other Cells in the Master Sheet.  I'm not sure I'm explaining this in a very good way, sorry.

Comment: Oh, I think your right. Let me see if I can change that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151071/discussion-between-cooper-and-luke).

Comment: Hi Cooper.  Apologies, I went on annual leave and have only just gotten back to work on this bit of code.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
function gatheringValues1()
{
  var mySheets=['NOV16','DEC16','JAN17','FEB17','MARCH17','APR17','MAY17','JUNE17','JULY17','AUGUST17']
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sht=ss.insertSheet('newSheet');
  sht.activate();
  var allSheets=ss.getSheets();
  var sumB3s=0;
  //var sumB3s='';
  for(var i=0;i<allSheets.length;i++)
  {
    if(mySheets.indexOf(allSheets[i].getName())>-1)
    {
      sumB3s+=Number(allSheets[i].getRange('B3').getValue());//not sure which one you want
      //sumB3s+=String(allSheets[i].getRange('B3').getValue());
    }
    sht.getRange('B3').setValue(sumB3s);
  }
}
```

Or perhaps this was what you were after:

```
function gatheringFormulas()
{
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh1=ss.getSheetByName('oldSheet');
  var rg1=sh1.getRange(2,2,10,10);
  var rg1A=rg1.getFormulas();
  var sh2=ss.getSheetByName('newSheet');
  var rg2=sh2.getRange(2,2,10,10);
  rg2.setFormulas(rg1A);
}
```